# Unable to import in ActionScript 3 in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I am playing with a large code-base and this is my first time with ActionScript (version 3). Below is the directory structure.

```
MyProject(AS3)
  bin
  src
    backend
    ui
      src
        com 
          company
            events
              MyEvent.as  
            scripts
              MyViewer.as
        MyViewer.mxml
```

`MyViewer.mxml` is the Document Class, and it has a statement:

```
<fx:Script source="com/company/scripts/MyViewer.as"/>
```

`MyViewer.as` imports the `MyEvent` class as:

```
import com.company.events.MyEvent;
```

When I build (`F8`) the project, I get an error like:

```
C:\path\MyViewer.as(155):  Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MyEvent.
```

Edit: Please note that, the statement where this error is thrown is not the one with import statement. The error is shown on the line where the class is actually referred. For example line 155 in is the following:

```
private function SuccessHandler(event:MyEvent):void {  // line 155
    // some code
}
```

Comment: you need: `import com.company.events.MyEvent`,  the `SearchEvent` class is not the same as the `MyEvent` class

Comment: It was `MyEvent`. I copied a wrong statement while posting the question here. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If you right-click the `src` folder in Flashdevelop,  does it have a checkmark beside "source path" ?

Comment: The top level src has a checkmark beside "source path"

Comment: May be a bad question, but do I need to compile `MyEvent.as` first? Build should have already done that, right?

Comment: No, individual .as files are not pre-compiled.  Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: Many other similar errors. There are many classes that I am importing. Whenever any of those class is referred in the code, I get an error corresponding to that. Please note that the error is not shown at the import statement, but when the class gets used actually.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I marked the lower-level src folder as the "source path".